# What's happened to the Daily Visitors figure in the Site Stats sidebar?

Tags: bug

If I remember correctly, it used to show approx 13,000 visitors a day on SQA but that number started showing as 1000, and then 50, and then 3, and now it's disappeared entirely.

I thought it was a bug at first, but it may have been removed intentionally. Does anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the sites in Area 51 shows many of them with 0 visits, which I find very, very hard to believe.

It's obviously a bug of some kind (if the feature was removed, so should the display of the feature.)

I will raise it with the SE devs. Thanks for bringing it up!